# ssh command returns immediately is piped to a file but when not return if just sent to a variable

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I have a problem with a script that makes ssh calls. I want the script to wait for the remote command to complete. It does when I assign the output to a variable like:

```
 command=($(ssh -f user@host "cd <dir>; start_script.sh))
```

The problems is the when I echo $command it appears each word is on a separate line but all the output is in the variable.

When I am add piping to a file, it no longer waits for the command to complete but immediately returns control back to the local script.

```
 command=($(ssh -f user@host "cd <dir>; start_script.sh >> file.txt))
```

When I cat the file only a small portion of the output is in the file.

How can I get the local script to wait for the remote script to complete and get the output back line by line?

Comment: Are you sure the control is back to local script not because of any error? I tested the code with sleep in `start_script.sh`. The control to local script didn't return immediately. Only after the `start_script.sh` was done completely.

Comment: Your problem seems to be from the format of your line. Try the command line like this, and it should work as you want:
`command=$(ssh user@host "cd <dir>; start_script.sh")`

Comment: Yes I left out the trailing quote by mistake. What I really want is this command:  command=($(ssh -f user@host "cd <dir>; start_script.sh >> file.txt)). Where I am piping the output to a file at the same time I am updating a variable,"command". The problem is when I add the piping to the file it doesn't wait for start_script.sh to complete but immediately returns control to the local script. Without the piping to the file it waits until start_script.sh completes before continuing the local script.